# Find the different set.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Find the different set:

(i) $\ \ (\emptyset \cup \{\emptyset\})\cup \{0\}$

(ii) $\ \{\emptyset , \{\emptyset\} , 0\}$

(iii) $\{\emptyset, 0 \}$

I think it is (iii), as (i) & (ii) are same, but the correct answer is (ii). Why?

Comment: What set is $0$ to you? Or is it not a set?

Comment: @Arthur It is an element, not a member of any set. However, here in all 3 examples, it is a member of set.

Comment: I assume $\phi$ stands for the empty set $\emptyset$.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Yes, it is.

Comment: I think the set i) is $(\emptyset \cup \{\emptyset\}) \cup \{0\}$.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco So, sorry for the typo.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco - I strongly support your conjecture: as written, i) and iii) are **not** the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\emptyset$ has no elements, then $\emptyset \cup \{\emptyset\} = \{\emptyset\}$. Therefore, (i) and (iii) are equal, because

\begin{align}
(\emptyset \cup \{\emptyset\}) \cup \{0\} = \{\emptyset\} \cup \{0\} =\{\emptyset, 0\}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot for that.

Comment: It clarifies the question totally. Also, thanks for pointing out the typos.

Comment: Seemingly the long interval required to wait before accepting, made me forget that. Will take care in future.

Answer (score 2):

(i) and (iii) are the same. Let's take a look at (i):

Ignoring the ")", the first set is a Union of emptyset and a set that contains the emptyset, resulting in a set that contains the emptyset. Now we have a Union with the second set containing "$0$", resulting in (iii).

What is important here:
$\emptyset \cup \{ \emptyset \}$ is not the same as $\emptyset , \{ \emptyset \}$. Realize that the first expression is giving you one element, second is giving you two.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA Have corrected it in OP.